# What is the name of this menu-like layout item on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I see this layout item in a lot of apps but I don't know the name. What is the name of this layout item pictured in the images below?

Image 1
[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89374609/imgs/stackover/Screenshot_2014-03-24-14-32-16.png]

Image 2

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89374609/imgs/stackover/Screenshot_2014-03-24-14-33-11.png]

Comment: Not 100% sure but I guess they're [Contextual Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) Take a look, new to android too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the `PopupMenu` class.

Also, this is used for the overflow menu in the Action Bar, you can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

Answer (score 0):

They are [menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html), read official docs.

[Contextual Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) are used when you need to show a list of choices, example when you long press in a item in ListView.